# Mover uma div e remove-la para liberar conteudo atras

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```css
.atras{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.frente{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #aaa;
  }
```

```html
<div class="atras">  
  <a href="#">abrir div </a>
</div>


<div class="frente">  
  <a href="#">fechar div</a>
</div>
```

queria fazer aqui um animação

ao clicar no botão sair a div que está na frente rola para a direita e some.
ao clicar no botao abrir a div volta da direita até ocupar a tela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo simples com js puro. Vc tem que pegar o link clicado e fazer um `classList.add` ou `classList.remove`. A classe que vc vai adicionar tem um `left` de 100% e `scaleX(0)` isso vai jogar a `div` para fora da tela. Mas para não criar uma barra de rolagem horizontal vc tem que colocar `overflow-x: hidden` no `body`. Para deixar o efeito suave, coloque um `transition` na `div` que vai sair da tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seque o código da imagem acima:

```js
const out = document.querySelector('.frente > a');
const on = document.querySelector('.atras > a');

out.addEventListener('click', sai);
on.addEventListener('click', entra);

function sai() {
    const frente = document.querySelector('.frente');
    frente.classList.add('out')
}

function entra() {
    const frente = document.querySelector('.frente');
    frente.classList.remove('out')
}
```

```css
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.atras {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.frente {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #aaa;

    transform-origin: right;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 500ms;
}

.frente.out {
    left: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="atras">
    <a href="#">abrir div </a>
</div>


<div class="frente">
    <a href="#">fechar div</a>
</div>
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente pro que eu precisava, muito obrigado hugo! mas me diz pra que serve `scaleX(0)` e esse `transform-origin` ?

Comment: @leonardovita scaleX eh para colocar a largura do elemento com 0 de escala horizontal, tipo width 0, e o transform-origen e para determinar por onde eu quero que o transfor acontece, tipo da direita pra esquerda ou o contrario. Se a resposta resolveu o problema lembre-se de marcar uma delas com o ✔ abaixo das setinhas da resposta que vc escolher

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Primeiro altere o `position` da `div.frente` de `absolute` para `fixed` para evitar a barra de rolagem horizontal ao movê-la para fora da janela, e adicione a propriedade `transition` que irá fazer a animação no CSS:

```
.frente{
   position: fixed; /* POSITION ALTERADO */
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;

   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   background: #aaa;

   transition: right .5s ease-in; /* ANIMAÇÃO */
}
```

Agora crie uma classe para a div onde o `right` será `-100vw`, fazendo com que a div se mova para fora da tela à direita:

```
.frente.sai{
   right: -100vw;
}
```

Quando a `div.frente` ganhar a classe `.sai`, irá disparar o `transition`, onde você pode ajustar o tempo e o tipo de transição: coloquei `.5s`, que são 500 milissegundos ou meio segundo, e `ease-in` ([uma lista de tipos de transições você pode ver neste documento](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)).

Coloque uma classe nas tags `<a>` "abrir div" e "fechar div" que irá facilitar bastante no código JS e irá evitar que outros links que você poderá ter na página ative a animação. Coloque a mesma classe nas duas tags. No exemplo abaixo coloquei a classe `.controle`:

```
<div class="atras">  
   <a class="controle" href="#">abrir div </a>
</div>

<div class="frente">  
   <a class="controle" href="#">fechar div</a>
</div>
```

Feito isso, basta fazer um *toggle* da classe `.sai` na `div.frente`. Um `toggle` basicamente é inserir/retirar a classe do elemento cada vez que é chamado.

Em jQuery ficaria assim:

```
$(".controle").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".frente").toggleClass("sai");
});
```

Em JS puro assim:

```
const controles = document.querySelectorAll(".controle");
for(let el of controles){
   el.onclick = function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      document.querySelector(".frente").classList.toggle("sai");
   }
}
```

> O `e.preventDefault();` é para evitar que o `href="#"` acrescente a hash
>   `#` no final da URL da página.

Vou colocar um exemplo abaixo usando jQuery, mas você pode trocar pela versão em JS puro se quiser:

```js
$(".controle").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".frente").toggleClass("sai");
});
```

```css
.atras{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.frente{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   background: #aaa;
   
   transition: right .5s ease-in;
}

.frente.sai{
   right: -100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="atras">  
   <a class="controle" href="#">abrir div </a>
</div>

<div class="frente">  
   <a class="controle" href="#">fechar div</a>
</div>
```

Comment: a resposta do hugo acima resolveu meu problema. mas mesmo sim sua resposta tabem e muito boa. só um pouco mais complicada, obrigado mesmo assim

Comment: Tranquilo, mas a minha resposta é bem mais simples, pq usa muito menos código e apenas uma função.